# Can we find uncountably many disjoint measurable subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ with strictly postive Lebesgue measure?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Can we find uncountably many disjoint measurable subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ with strictly positive Lebesgue measure?

Comment: I think we can't find uncountably many disjoint measurable subsets, if so, we can find uncountabely many disjoint closed subsets with postive measure, but every such closed set at least contains a rational number.

Comment: The irrationals have positive measure.

Comment: Hint: If we could, there would have to be uncountably many disjoint measurable subsets of some $[a,b]$ (for finite $a$ and $b$), each with positive measure. Think through the implications of that.

Comment: Andres Caicedo, I think Shine meant each of the subsets has strictly positive measure.  What would your uncountably many disjoint subsets be?

Comment: @user46944 I am indicating that the argument in Shine's comment is essentially flawed.

Comment: @bof, but their measure are not positive.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If it were possible, for some integer $n$ we would be able to find uncountably many of your sets that meet the interval $[n,n+1]$ in a set of positive measure. But then for some positive integer $m$, uncountably many of them would meet it in a set of measure strictly larger than $1/m$. This is impossible, since the union of any $m+1$ of them would be a measurable subset of $[n,n+1]$ of measure strictly larger than $1$.

Comment: For those interested, some related but more sophisticated results are discussed in my [13 May 2005 sci.math post](http://mathforum.org/kb/message.jspa?messageID=3767449) at Math Forum.